# Como projetar um aplicativo cliente socket básico

Tags: android, socket, websocket, chat

Em primeiro lugar peço desculpas pelo texto longo, e pelos vários pontos perguntados. Achei melhor lançar todos em uma pergunta só porque são interrelacionados e porque penso que qualquer pessoa com experiência no tipo de aplicativo descrito (um cliente Android que mantém uma conexão socket contínua recebendo e enviando dados) é capaz de dar sua opinião a respeito de todos ou maioria desses pontos. Basicamente estou precisando tomar decisões de design e tenho dúvidas sobre como seria a "maneira recomendada Android" de fazer.

Estou tentando definir qual seria o esqueleto mínimo necessário para se ter um aplicativo dsse tipo, isto é, que se conecte a um servidor via *socket* (WebSocket, Socket.IO, TCP, etc.) e possa trocar mensagens com ele). Não tenho um exemplo de uso específico; chat não é um desses exemplos, porque nesse caso o ideal seria usar *push notification*.

Essa conexão não deve estar atrelada às `Activities` do aplicativo, isto é, as mensagens podem ser recebidas mesmo depois do usuário ter saído do aplicativo.

Perguntas que estou tentando responder:

1. É recomendado delegar o gerenciamento da conexão (conectar, desconectar) e o envio de mensagens para uma classe separada (por exemplo um *Singleton*)?
2. O uso de *broadcasts* para passar uma mensagem recebida para a `Activity` atual parece ser a escolha apropriada no caso de uma arquitetura de aplicativo relativamente simples. Alguém discorda? Seria preferível um *Event Bus* ou então acoplamento (*bind*) a um serviço?
3. É esperado que o sistema mate o processo do aplicativo para liberar memória, mas a conexão deve ser reestabelecida assim que houver memória disponível para isso. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? Agendar checagens periódicas da conexão via `AlarmManager` não me parece apropriado, e nem usar `startForeground()`, que além de não garantir que o processo seja morto (apenas torna isso menos provável de acontecer) ainda exibe ao usuário uma incômoda notificação de que o aplicativo está em execução, que ainda por cima se for clicada leva a uma tela oferecendo a opção de encerrar o aplicativo. Achei que retornar `START_STICKY` no método `Service.startCommand()` poderia ajudar nesse sentido, mas ele [não parece ser feito para isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441795/2241463).
4. Não estou certo de como deve funcionar o reestabelecimento de conexão, a fim de processar a fila de mensagens a enviar. Suponho que envolve ouvir o *broadcast* `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` ou então um evento de conexão reestabelecida. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso, garantindo que o aplicativo tente enviar as mensagens quando possível?
5. Após haver consenso a respeito da modelagem do aplicativo, creio que será necessário incluir *Wake Locks* ao código para evitar que o aparelho entre em *sleep mode* enquanto processa mensagens recebidas ou colocadas na fila de envio. Porém não tenho certeza de em qual parte do código inclui-las e gostaria de recomendações. Para isso tenho também as seguintes considerações adicionais:

   a) Uma vez a conexão estabelecida, o aparelho pode entrar em *sleep mode* tranquilamente que a chegada de dados irá acordá-lo. Porém não é garantido que esses dados sejam processados em sua completude sem uma *Wake Lock*, antes do aparelho voltar a dormir;

   b) Se o aplicativo estiver adormecido e a conexão se tornar disponível, um requisito desejável pode ser que a fila de mensagens a enviar seja processada em sua completude antes do aparelho voltar a dormir. Não tenho a certeza de onde devo adicionar a *Wake Lock* nesse caso.

   c) Mesmo que a biblioteca que trabalha com o protocolo de comunicação escolhido esteja preparada para funcionar com Android (isto é, gerencie a entrada/saída em um ou mais *threads* secundários e não no *thread* de *UI*), pode ser que ela esteja programada para executar seus *callbacks* (em particular o *callback* que recebe mensagens) no *thread* de *UI*. Isso pode afetar a maneira como disponho as *Wake Locks* no meu código.
6. Há a necessidade de manter um *thread* ativo em loop contínuo para manter a conexão aberta? Como posso evitar isso?

Agradeço a qualquer feedback. Lancei essa pergunta também no [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411655/pattern-or-best-practice-for-a-simple-socket-client-app-possibly-chat).

Comment: Piovezan, chegou a considerar o GCM como forma de implementar o Push notifications? Tenho uma sugestão pra dar, mas envolve o mesmo, quando eu tiver tempo eu posto uma resposta.

Comment: Então, a idéia nesse caso é não usar push notification; eu tenho como exemplo um aplicativo que mantenha a conexão aberta somente enquanto o usuário estiver "logado" nele por exemplo, e perca a conexão ao deslogar. Não existe a obrigatoriedade de que as mensagens sejam entregues ao cliente se a conexão estiver fechada. São dados de vida curta e dispensáveis, como por exemplo em um aplicativo que  comanda uma central de alarme instalada em uma residência.

Comment: 1. Questão de gosto, acho que o Service já é a classe que toma conta das questões de rede.

2. Broadcast é o mais simples de usar, mas seria mais "limpo" um bind direto entre Activity e Service. Não sei como ficam as questões de segurança/privacidade ao usar broadcast; a priori cada aplicativo precisa de permissão para receber determinado broadcast.

3. Você pode rodar o Service num processo separado (process e isolatedProcess no manifesto). Isso faz com que use menos memória e diminui a chance de ser morto. Pelo menos no meu uso, nunca aconteceu de um serviço rodando assim ser de fato morto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acabei implementando parte desses requisitos e resolvendo a maioria das dúvidas. Segue o que aprendi com isso.

Antes porém, uma recomendação: socket no Android pode não ser o que você quer. Quando implementei, o que realmente eu precisava era de *push notifications* (por exemplo, com Google Cloud Messaging). Portanto, antes de se decidir por uma determinada tecnologia, estude todas as possibilidades.

> É recomendado delegar o gerenciamento da conexão (conectar,
>   desconectar) e o envio de mensagens para uma classe separada (por
>   exemplo um Singleton)?

Tanto faz. Se for usado Singleton, ele estará tão intimamente ligado com o serviço que o resultado será o mesmo que implementar somente o serviço. Como falado na resposta do @LeonardoBosquett, algumas pessoas considerarem Singleton um *anti-pattern* e preferem não usar.

> O uso de broadcasts para passar uma mensagem recebida para a Activity
>   atual parece ser a escolha apropriada no caso de uma arquitetura de
>   aplicativo relativamente simples. Alguém discorda? Seria preferível um
>   Event Bus ou então acoplamento (bind) a um serviço?

Alguns preferem *bind*, outros broadcasts. Se usada a segunda opção é preferível fazer broadcasts locais com `LocalBroadcastManager`, que têm melhor performance comparados a broadcasts globais.

> É esperado que o sistema mate o processo do aplicativo para liberar
>   memória, mas a conexão deve ser reestabelecida assim que houver
>   memória disponível para isso. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? (...)
>   Achei que retornar START_STICKY no método Service.startCommand()
>   poderia ajudar nesse sentido, mas ele não parece ser feito para isso.

Estava enganado, `START_STICKY` serve justamente para isso. Porém de acordo com a documentação o serviço é reiniciado com um intent `null`, então se houver parâmetros para ler do intent a solução é usar `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`.

> Não estou certo de como deve funcionar o reestabelecimento de conexão,
>   a fim de processar a fila de mensagens a enviar. Suponho que envolve
>   ouvir o broadcast CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE ou então um evento de conexão
>   reestabelecida. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso, garantindo que o
>   aplicativo tente enviar as mensagens quando possível?

Essa parte não foi implementada e não tenho uma resposta imediata para isso. Em um evento de conexão estabelecida gerado pela biblioteca de comunicação o serviço pode processar a fila assim que adquirir uma *Wake Lock*.

Dúvida: Dada a forma como funciona TCP, suspeito que uma `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` de perda de conectividade possa não disparar uma `IOException` imediatamente; pode ser que seja preciso avisar o serviço de que a conexão foi perdida para que ele finalize ativamente a conexão. Se isso for o caso, teria que ser pensada uma forma de comunicar ao serviço que ocorreu a perda de conectividade. Da mesma forma, é preciso pensar em como avisar ao serviço sobre um restabelecimento de conectividade para tentar se conectar novamente (por economia de bateria, é recomendável que seja feito um *exponential back-off*, que em caso de conectividade restabelecida pode reiniciar do zero).

> c) Mesmo que a biblioteca que trabalha com o protocolo de comunicação
>   escolhido esteja preparada para funcionar com Android (isto é,
>   gerencie a entrada/saída em um ou mais threads secundários e não no
>   thread de UI), pode ser que ela esteja programada para executar seus
>   callbacks (em particular o callback que recebe mensagens) no thread de
>   UI. Isso pode afetar a maneira como disponho as Wake Locks no meu
>   código.

A preocupação aqui é quando adquirir a *Wake Lock*. São duas situações em que ela é necessária: ao receber uma mensagem e ao processar a fila de mensagens a enviar. No primeiro caso ela pode ser adquirida assim que for recebida uma mensagem e liberada assim que terminar de processar a mesma. No segundo ela pode ser adquirida quando ocorre reconexão com o servidor.

> b) Se o aplicativo estiver adormecido e a conexão se tornar
>   disponível, um requisito desejável pode ser que a fila de mensagens a
>   enviar seja processada em sua completude antes do aparelho voltar a
>   dormir. Não tenho a certeza de onde devo adicionar a Wake Lock nesse
>   caso.

A preocupação aqui é quando liberar a *Wake Lock* adquirida para processar a fila de mensagens a enviar. Ela precisaria ser removida em dois locais: caso o processamento da fila termine (seja naturalmente ou caso ocorra uma `IOException` sinalizando quebra de conexão) e no `onDestroy()` do serviço. O primeiro caso em termos de código ficaria mais ou menos assim (emprestando do código do @LeonardoBosquett):

```
wakeLock.acquire();
try {
    this.processQueue();
catch (IOException e) {
    // Lida com a exceção de alguma forma
} finally {
    wakeLock.release();
}
```

> Há a necessidade de manter um thread ativo em loop contínuo para
>   manter a conexão aberta? Como posso evitar isso?

Depende da forma como a biblioteca de comunicação é implementada. Preferencialmente o thread pode se bloquear aguardando a chegada de uma mensagem, não é preciso que fique em execução.

Answer (score 5):

Tudo depende da aplicação que você quer fazer, vou responder de maneira genérica para que você aplique o uso em diferentes ocasiões.

> 1. É recomendado delegar o gerenciamento da conexão (conectar, desconectar) e o envio de mensagens para uma classe separada (por
>      exemplo um Singleton)?

Veja isto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Alguns programadores consideram Singleton um "anti-pattern", evite usá-lo, ele pode lhe traz barreiras enquanto desenvolve a aplicação. Mas sim, você deve ter uma classe especializada em receber conexões, outra para criar conexões e uma compartilhada pelas duas anteriores para transmitir suas mensagens, reduza o escopo à isto nessa fase para evitar qualquer acoplamento desnecessário (Activties por exemplo, estas classes não sabem que elas existem).

> 2. O uso de broadcasts para passar uma mensagem recebida para a Activity atual parece ser a escolha apropriada no caso de uma
>      arquitetura de aplicativo relativamente simples. Alguém discorda?
>      Seria preferível um Event Bus ou então acoplamento (bind) a um
>      serviço?

O aplicativo é simples, logo seu código deve ser simples, mas em ocasiões em que múltiplas Activities podem receber mensagens, notificações, alertas, etc delegue todas estas tarefas à um "Bound Service".

> http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Utilize do serviço para enviar e receber mensagens através da rede e o mesmo poderá criar notificações sobre novas mensagens.

> 3. É esperado que o sistema mate o processo do aplicativo para liberar memória, mas a conexão deve ser reestabelecida assim que houver
>      memória disponível para isso. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?
>      Agendar checagens periódicas da conexão via AlarmManager não me parece
>      apropriado, e nem usar startForeground(), que além de não garantir que
>      o processo seja morto (apenas torna isso menos provável de acontecer)
>      ainda exibe ao usuário uma incômoda notificação de que o aplicativo
>      está em execução, que ainda por cima se for clicada leva a uma tela
>      oferecendo a opção de encerrar o aplicativo. Achei que retornar
>      START_STICKY no método Service.startCommand() poderia ajudar nesse
>      sentido, mas ele não parece ser feito para isso.

de maneira geral, mantenha isto simples:

1. Ao criar o serviço: Abrir conexão
2. Fechar o serviço (não é garantido que seja chamado): Tentar fechar conexão.
3. Service não dispõe de um método "onServiceRestoreState" ou algo do tipo, então você pode se aproveitar dos métodos `onDestroy`, `onUnbind`, `onTrimMemory`, `startForeGround`, `stopForeground` para desfazer a conexão. utilize isto também: [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT). Isto fará com que  onStartCommand seja chamado novamente e você possa restabelecer a conexão.

sobre o AlarmManager:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411744/android-when-a-service-is-killed-how-can-we-persist-the-service-state-for-late

O uso do AlarmManager é designado para tarefas que devem ser executadas de tempos em tempos, como diz na questão acima,

> O uso intensivo de um serviço é hostil.

Dica: Você não precisa estar escutando por novas mensagens ou notificações de um servidor o tempo todo (imagine a carga de memória de um servidor com várias conexões abertas, muitas talvez sem transmitir dados por longos períodos). Faça verificações periódicas (que seja a cada 1 minuto se tão necessário, abra conexão com o servidor, verifique e feche-a).

> 4. Não estou certo de como deve funcionar o reestabelecimento de conexão, a fim de processar a fila de mensagens a enviar. Suponho que
>      envolve ouvir o broadcast CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE ou então um evento de
>      conexão reestabelecida. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso, garantindo
>      que o aplicativo tente enviar as mensagens quando possível?

É trivial, mas existem aspectos que devem ser considerados: Sim, cheque CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE para saber se tem ou não conexão disponível

> [Monitorando conexões](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

Trate exceções de Socket, Tcp, etc (você pode ter rede no dispositivo, mas o servidor pode estar offline ou ocorrer algum erro de rede) como conexão perdida em sua implementação. na realização de qualquer ação: tentativa de enviar mensagem, ler notificações do servidor verifique este "estado desconectado" e se desconectado tente reconectar para enviar a requisição.

Quando estiver offline ou receber uma exceção limpe os recursos (Dispose Socket, Tcp, etc), quando tentar reconectar você os criará novamente.

Mas em resumo: Quando **realizar operações de rede** você **trata o estado da conexão**.

> 5. Após haver consenso a respeito da modelagem do aplicativo, creio que será necessário incluir Wake Locks ao código para evitar que o
>      aparelho entre em sleep mode enquanto processa mensagens recebidas ou
>      colocadas na fila de envio. Porém não tenho certeza de em qual parte
>      do código inclui-las e gostaria de recomendações. Para isso tenho
>      também as seguintes considerações adicionais:
>
> a) Uma vez a conexão
>   estabelecida, o aparelho pode entrar em sleep mode tranquilamente que
>   a chegada de dados irá acordá-lo. Porém não é garantido que esses
>   dados sejam processados em sua completude sem uma Wake Lock, antes do
>   aparelho voltar a dormir;

O [WakeLook](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) é projetado para impedir que o aparelho entre em Idle, mas isto não é um meio vivável de acordá-lo quando receber uma notificação/mensagem.

O mais indicado neste caso seria o [WifiLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) que impede que o dispositivo de rede seja desligado quando o dispositivo móvel entrar em Idle.

você utilizará o método `aquire` para dizer que o dispositivo não pode desligar seu dispositivo de rede e `release` depois de fechar as conexões, encerrar o serviço ou encerrar as ações do aplicativo.

> b) Se o aplicativo estiver adormecido e a
>   conexão se tornar disponível, um requisito desejável pode ser que a
>   fila de mensagens a enviar seja processada em sua completude antes do
>   aparelho voltar a dormir. Não tenho a certeza de onde devo adicionar a
>   Wake Lock nesse caso.

tanto para WakeLock como WifiLock:

```
 wakeLock.acquire();
 this.processQueue();
 wakeLock.release();
```

> c) Mesmo que a biblioteca que trabalha com o
>   protocolo de comunicação escolhido esteja preparada para funcionar com
>   Android (isto é, gerencie a entrada/saída em um ou mais threads
>   secundários e não no thread de UI), pode ser que ela esteja programada
>   para executar seus callbacks (em particular o callback que recebe
>   mensagens) no thread de UI. Isso pode afetar a maneira como disponho
>   as Wake Locks no meu código.

Sim, mantenha os WakeLocks dentro das classes que gerenciam as mensagens (como acoplamento, talvez um IoC aqui) e tente manter o código "Thread-Safe", o resto fica por conta da injeção de dependência.

> 6. Há a necessidade de manter um thread ativo em loop contínuo para manter a conexão aberta? Como posso evitar isso?

se você precisa da conexão aberta o tempo todo: Sim (não recomendado) em alguma Thread ela precisará estar (isto é inevitável), não precisa ser em loop, mas o processo pode estar em Idle, à espera das mensagens.
Manter uma conexão aberta por longos períodos é bem propenso à falhas (principalmente redes móveis), considere que o cliente questione ao servidor sobre notificações em longos períodos em vez de manter a conexão aberta e esperar por mensagens.